# Regular expression help for replacing elements of urls within dynamic content

Tags: php, regex, image

There are lots of URL finding regEx's and I am probably missing a trick in being able to work out how to adapt them to my needs but RegEx and I do not get on.

Situation:  I am loading dynamic content in with PHP/mySQL which contains various  img tags with srcs that I need to modify.

E.g:

```
Blah blah <img src="/oldsite/images/image1.gif" alt="image blah" title="image blah" /> blah blah <img src="/otheroldsite/images/image2.gif" alt="image blah" title="image blah" />
```

I need to remove anything between  img src="   and  images/....
"anything" is the key bit here as I there may be a whole range of "root folders" in the content

to end up with

```
Blah blah <img src="images/image1.gif" alt="image blah" title="image blah" /> blah blah <img src="images/image2.gif" alt="image blah" title="image blah" />
```

Many thanks in advance, I know you guys can do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
preg_replace("/src=\"(.*?)\/images/", "src=\"images", $string)
```

Comment: Thanks user113236...
I get Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: I always run into this sort of thing and usually give up on RegEx about now.  Really appreciate your input.

Comment: I have run with this: $outputThis = preg_replace('/src=\"(.*?)\/images/', 'src=images', $outputThis);

but, for some reason, I end up with an extra " at the end of each URL (not there to start with)

Comment: was being an idiot, sorry - all sorted
$outputThis = preg_replace('/src=\"(.*?)\/images/', 'src="images', $outputThis);

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Try this

```
(?<=img src=").*?(?=images\/)
```

and replace with the empty string.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30ciu)

Basically you match as less as possible any characters (except newlines) with `.*?`, where `(?<=img src=")` ensures that there is `img src="` on the left and `(?=images\/)` ensures that there is `images\/` on the right.

A group `(...)` starting with `?<=` is called **positive lookbehind assertion** and a group starting with `?=` is called **positive lookahead assertion**

Comment: Thanks stema. Really helpful and good link. I have been building web pages for over 12 years, in coldfusion, asp, php, .net but, for some reason my brain doesn't process RegEx syntax at all.

Comment: You are welcome, [http://www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) is in general a good regular expression resource.

Comment: Argh now I meet the stage in PHP where I get "Unknown modifier '.'" when using $pattern = '(?<=img src=").*?(?=userassets\/)';
I do hate this stuff.   :)

Comment: You need regex delimiters around your regex `$pattern = '/(?<=img src=").*?(?=userassets\/)/';`